# Scala list print issue -- IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the following code

```
object DispatchLibrary
{
  private var nodes = Map.empty[java.util.UUID, List[BigInt]]

  def addNode(uuid: java.util.UUID) = if(nodes contains uuid) nodes else (nodes += (uuid -> Nil))

  def addValue(uuid: java.util.UUID, value: BigInt) = nodes + (uuid -> (value :: (nodes get uuid getOrElse Nil)))

  //def getValue(uuid: java.util.UUID) : List[BigInt] = ???

  //def getValues() : List[BigInt] = ???

  def calculated(): Boolean = !nodes.exists(_._1 eq null)

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit =
  {
    val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()

    addNode(uuid)
    addValue(uuid, BigInt(999))
    addValue(uuid, BigInt(9999))

    nodes foreach {case (key, value) => println (key + "->" + value)}
  }
}
```

Running the above code in IntelliJ IDEA gives something similar to the following output

```
8b2b4a7b-3e65-4de0-9035-8ee1d2910983->List()
```

I am not sure why the List is not being printed.

Running a similar code from the REPL gives the expected output

```
scala> var nodes = Map.empty[Int, List[BigInt]]
nodes: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[BigInt]] = Map()

scala> nodes += (1->Nil)

scala> nodes += (1 -> (BigInt(999) :: (nodes get 1 getOrElse Nil)))

scala> nodes += (1 -> (BigInt(9999) :: (nodes get 1 getOrElse Nil)))

scala> nodes foreach {case (key, value) => println (key + "-->" + value )}
1-->List(9999, 999)
```

I would appreciate also if you could help me in writing the commented methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `addValue` method you write `nodes + (uuid -> (value :: (nodes get uuid getOrElse Nil)))` which does not change the list in `nodes`, but only creates a new copy with the value added. Since `Map` is immutable by default you'll have to store it like you do with the `=`-sign in the `addNode` method.

The reason it prints anything at all is because the first entry consists of a UUID (String) and Nil (empty List). The "8b2b4a7b-3e65-4de0-9035-8ee1d2910983" makes sense then because it's the UUID. The "List()" is a result of printing Nil (since it is an empty List).

And there you have it. Try writing `node += ...` in the `addValue` in stead.

Comment: I can't believe what small mistakes can do. Thanks :)

Comment: What about the second part of the question. I am trying to write `getValues()` methods which should return a list of all the values

Comment: @Nabegh `def getValue(uuid: java.util.UUID) = nodes(uuid)` and `def getValues = nodes.values.flatten`

Comment: Although the latter will return `Iterable`, so you might want to call `toList` on it.

Comment: @Nabegh: Yeah it's really horrible how much a single "=" can do :-) Glad I could help.